# So, what do we do when we don't want to ask questions?

Tags: social-network, social, community

First off, lemme just say, I'm totally in love with this site -- if one can have romantic feelings toward a few hundred-thousand characters of php, that is.

But, sometimes I feel like all this Q&A is missing the point of the first word in it's title. "Social."

So, as posed above, what do we do when we don't want to ask questions and we simply want to talk?

Comment: maybe lets start a thread with messengers adresses to fill this "gap"?

Comment: @Pretaeperon, Even though I wouldn't mind, in this era of information it's RISKY... risky... r i s k y . . . (that's an echo btw :D). For the social thing, we're doing it quite well I think: I don't remember who was trading a sound effect against a day of watching the other person at work, there've been some talking going on about meetups... to be honest, I would love more contact with you people, but I'd say it's only a matter of finding a place in this industry. It's all a big family in the end! But hey go on, I didn't mean to interrupt ;)

Comment: im not going to take your home adress =D

Answer (score 11):

The whole point of Stack Exchange is to *prevent* chatty discussions.  It exists because "just talking" has a terrible signal-to-noise ratio and is a waste of time for anyone who's just trying to find an answer to something.

There are already tons of websites for socializing, called forums.  If you end up on one from a Google search, you have to wade through dozens of pages of people arguing, stating erroneous things as truth, stupid signatures, etc. in order to find a tiny partial nugget of information which may or may not be outdated or wrong.

https://stackoverflow.com/about

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38315/partner-with-traditional-forums-to-support-open-ended-discussions#answer-38323

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8658/do-you-feel-stackoverflow-needs-a-general-discussion-forum

Comment: I realize that, and I've been around those forums way too many times.  We need a private forum just for ourselves, for just talking, in my opinion.

Comment: love the analogy 

Answer (score 8):

Yeah I gotta say, I enjoy the format of the site the way it is. Everyone posing intelligent pointed questions, searching for discussions about specific topics through tags, I don't have to wade through a bunch of BS that I don't want to.

Sure, it might be nice to have an additional resource that would allow more direct communication. Something like a Social Sound Design Facebook group or similar use of existing site design. I'm not really knowledgeable about all that. But something like that would allow us all to be connected and have the ability to chat through messaging or wall posts, etc.

But as far as this site goes, I'd prefer to see it clear of all that chatter and stick with its intended purpose. As @Andrew put it "a community-driven knowledge exchange."

Comment: Great ideas, Steve. The Facebook connection is intriguing…

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Great idea, I'll set up a Facebook group! 

Comment: :) Glad the subtle nudge helped @Andrew!

Answer (score 3):

I do all my socializing through twitter.  Most of the guys that frequent SSD are all friends on Twitter as well and we have candid conversation throughout most of every day.

My handle is @Colinhart if anyone wants to join in!

There also tends to be a decent amount of commenting between blogs and all.

As for SSD, I think it serves it's purpose well.  If conversation was allowed to become more candid, we'd turn into Gearslutz.  I can barely find any useful information over there amongst all the BS, Flaming, and random banter.

Comment: @Colin Do you ever check your e-mail?

Comment: @Ryan - yup, responding to your email now...

Comment: dang it, are you guys going to make me want to join twitter now? I've avoided it so well until now...

Comment: @Steve - from my experiences, it's not something you really want to avoid.  I've made a ton of connections and picked up a bunch of gigs from Twitter.  And gotten a lot of exposure.

Comment: Tweet tweet. Who knew?

Comment: @Colin Well, check it often!!!

Comment: @Ryan - goes right to my phone, so I know as soon as I get something! Sometimes I can't get back to you right away, but I do when I get a minute

Answer (score 2):

Well, I read, read, read.

But I can tell you I watched The Changeling (1979) last night.  One of the biggest reasons its the scariest movies of all time is its SOUND. First time I've watched it since becoming a sound designer, and a good lesson it was.

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys, thanks so much for the input! I've waited a bit to see what others have to say. The whole ethos of these SE sites is to be concise. I think we should stick to the way it is.

The comment system is a great way to interact more casually while staying somewhat focused on the question/answer.

As Collin says, Twitter is of course a fab environment for "socializing".

I love the idea of having a Facebook page for casual socializing! So here it is: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Social-Sound-Design/145661758787590

Please press **like** so that we start building it up. You can also check on the sidebar, I added a like button there too.

ps: If someone fancies designing a sexier and more interesting profile pic both for twitter and Facebook, please let me know :-)

Comment: A sexier pic? I think the upside down boobs are just fine... what? Is this not what it is? 8-)

Comment: haha! Now I can't get that out of my head... thanks! :-) 

Comment: Awesome.  I was actually surprised there wasn't a FB group already.

Comment: @Dave I know, I slacked on that one. I have so many things in my to do list, that this somehow never pushed in front. Thanks for your suggestion. I really like the idea of having a space for us to just chat. 

Answer (score 0):

WORK mostly, music, FB, WHISTLE professionally, game